# docker compose error open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I am breaking my head on below issue for past few hours.

docker compose is throwing error

`[emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

My docker componse version is v2.12.2

Below are my docker compose yaml and Dockerfile

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    frontend:
        build: ./frontend
        image: frontend_test
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.19-alpine

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

My project structure looks like below:

[image]

Strangely enough I am able to start the container using docker but it is not working with docker compose

Any help is appreciated?

I am expecting nignx container to start without any error.

Comment: Your screenshot does not show a `docker-compose.yaml` file.  Is it at the same level as the frontend directory? Also, what commands do you run to start the container with `docker` and `docker compose`?

Comment: @bsoren, could you please try this
COPY ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf